# in iOS11 CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey it doesnot work

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

in iOS11 it doesnot work,how to solve this problem except write the alert by myself? I still want to use to system one

Answer (score 0):

The missing system dialouge is filed in open radar: [CBCentralManager does not prompt the user to turn on Bluetooth on iOS 11](http://www.openradar.me/34576627)

It seems fixed with 11.1 but broken with 11.1.1 and then fixed with at least 11.2 beta 3.